# Contain snippet of word in array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, search

I don't know where to start asking but here's some rough code what am I going to do

```
arr = ['cat', 'dog']
if('housecat' not in arr):
        return TRUE
else return FALSE
```

What I want is: it return as TRUE because 'cat' was in the array while 'housecat' contain 'cat'.

==Edit==

I've tried code suggested

```
arr = ['cat', 'dog']
for i in arr:
        if(i not in 'housecat'):
                return TRUE
        else return FALSE
```

It return as TRUE as intended, but if there's symbol in the input (e.g: house-cat, cat.I (Only tested with those 2 symbol because input is automated)) it'll return as FALSE which should be TRUE (because there's 'cat' in house-'cat').

Edit 3: Should be return as TRUE not FALSE, my bad, edited the whole writing.

Edit 4: Case closed, bug appeared when I run the whole code and it has nothing to do with this case.

Comment: What should happen for caterpillar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
arr = ['cat', 'dog']
    for i in arr:
        if (i in 'housecat'):
            return false
    return true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

```
arr = ['cat', 'dog']
for item in arr:
  if item in "housecat":
      # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
arr = ['cat', 'dog']
is_housecat = lambda x: not any([i in 'housecat' for i in arr])

print(is_housecat(arr))
```

## Output

False